# XCTAssertEqual fails to compare two string values?

Tags: objective-c, unit-testing, xctest

I added a simple unit test to test my string extension. But it fails. What I am I doing wrong here?

From what I know `XCTAssertEqual` is testing value and not the object itself?

The third line btw, says the string are equal, but `XCTAssertEqual` says they're not.

```
- (void) testInitialsFromFullname {
    NSString *firstNickName = @"Mike Kain";
    NSString *expectedResult = @"MK";
    NSLog(@"Equal:%@", [[firstNickName initialsFromString] isEqualToString:expectedResult] ? @"YES" : @"NO");

    XCTAssertEqual(expectedResult, [firstNickName initialsFromString], @"Strings are not equal %@ %@", expectedResult, [firstNickName initialsFromString]);
}
```

Comment: This was a perfectly reasonable question, and I ran into the same issue when I first started with XCUnit. The accepted answer helped as well.

Answer (score 177, accepted):

From the documentation of `XCTAssertEqual`:

> Generates a failure when a1 is not equal to a2. **This test is for C
>   scalars, structs and unions.**

You should use `XCTAssertEqualObjects` (which uses `isEqual:` internally) or something like:

```
XCTAssertTrue([[firstNickName initialsFromString] isEqualToString:expectedResult],
              @"Strings are not equal %@ %@", expectedResult, [firstNickName initialsFromString]);
```

Comment: It seems that if you XCTAssertEqualObjects() two NSString objects they are compared with isEqualToString: automatically.

Comment: It uses `-isEquals:` under the hood all the time, but for `NSString` `-isEquals:` executes well-known `-isEqualToString:`. For instance, `NSNumber` implementation of `-isEquals:` method uses `-isEqualToNumber:`.

Comment: Unfortunately despite still being in the docs, as of Xcode 7.2 XCTAssertEqualObjects is no longer available.

Comment: XCAssertEqual(a, b) works just fine in XCode 7. This answer is not correct anymore.

Comment: XCTAssetEqualObjects is available in Xcode 8.0 and works for comparing NSStrings.

Comment: Using `XCTAssetEqualObjects` is better because if the test is failed, it will throw exactly the wrong string. `XCTAssertTrue` throws just only: "Oh it's not true"

Comment: This is actually a test smell. Don't do this.

Answer (score 15):

I've just had a similar issue which might help someone.

I have a Float extension function which returns a string. The following test fails:

```
testValue = 0.01
XCTAssertEqual(testValue.formattedForCost(), "0,01 €")
```

With the following message:

```
Assertions: XCTAssertEqual failed: ("Optional("0,01 €")") is not equal to ("Optional("0,01 €")")
```

Which is rather annoying. However I discovered if I change my test to use the [unicode no-break space character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00a0/index.htm):

```
XCTAssertEqual(testValue.formattedForCost(), "0,01\u{00a0}€")
```

It passes.

Comment: This worked for me too, but there's got to be a better solution.

Answer (score 3):

**Objective-C Comparing strings**

```
- (void) testStringComparison {
    NSString *first = @"my string";
    NSString *second = @"my string";
    
    NSMutableString *firstMutable = [NSMutableString stringWithString:first];

    //== comparing addresses of the objects(pointer comparison)
    //`first` and `second` has the same address it is a compiler optimization to store only one copy
    XCTAssertTrue(first == second);
    XCTAssertFalse(first == firstMutable);
    
    XCTAssertEqual(first, second);
    XCTAssertNotEqual(first, firstMutable);
    XCTAssertEqualObjects(first, firstMutable);
    XCTAssertTrue([first isEqualToString:firstMutable]);
}
```

Comment: do we expect all the assert calls result in true? I'm new into the unit testing

Comment: @gomozor, XCTAssertTrue expect TRUE, XCTAssertFalse expect FALSE. Expect means that a unit test is passed

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with string values apparently not being equal. I had to use the String `.compare` func, however, be aware that if you are testing string formatted for different Locales, you need to also pass the `locale` into the `compare` method. I assume that there are locale specific unicode characters in the string?

```
let expected = "9,32 EUR"

let actual = formattedPrice(for: price)

let locale = Locale(identifier: "fr_FR")

XCTAssertTrue(expected.compare(actual, locale: locale) == .orderedSame)
```