# Xcode: XCTest cannot no compare two NSArray of numbers

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsarray, xcode11.2.1

I'm trying to implement a unit test(`XCTest`) to compare two NSArray objects:

Here is my implementation:

```
- (void)testTwoNumsArrays {
    NSArray *result = @[@20,@20];
    NSArray *expecteResult = @[@20,@20];
    
    XCTAssertEqual(result, expecteResult);
}
```

I'm getting this error:

```
((result) equal to (expecteResult)) failed: ("{length = 8, bytes = 0xb0cfc00001000000}") is not equal to ("{length = 8, bytes = 0x9032ce0001000000}")
```

Any of you know why I can not compare the two arrays. In Swift it works just fine.

I'll really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are comparing the pointers to the objects and not the objects themselves.

XCTAssertEqual is essentially doing a check like the following, which is only comparing the pointer values.

```
if (a != b) assert();
```

You want something more along the lines of

```
if (![a isEqual:b]) assert();
```

This can be achieved with the XCTAssertEqualObjects call.

More information:

[XCTAssertEqual fails to compare two string values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19464261/xctassertequal-fails-to-compare-two-string-values)

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xctassertequalobjects